# jquery .hide uses {visibility:hidden;} is there alternative using {display:none;}

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

From my understanding using `.hide` in jquery uses (css) `{visibility:hidden;}` is there an alternative using `{display:none;}` ?

As doesn't a `{visibility:hidden;}` item still take up pixel space, where as with `{display:none;}` it hides the item and does not take up any space on screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, jQuery.hide() sets the display to none, here is proof [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/n3jWM/)

Answer (score 1):

I just double-checked the jquery code itself and confirmed that `.hide` works strictly with `display` property, setting it to `none`. `Visibility` stays `visible` on the element after `.hide`

Answer (score 1):

$(el).hide() uses display:none

You could also create your own 'hide' css class and add/remove that using jquery .addClass('hide') or .toggleClass('hide')

Answer (score 0):

NO, *The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none'), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.*

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` does set the CSS of the element to `display:none;`